# Css hover sometimes doesn't work on svg paths

Tags: html, css, svg

I got a svg with paths, and i have css hover on them, but hover sometimes work, sometimes not.

What can be the problem?

```
<div id="map_wrapper"> 
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
<g>
<title>Layer 1</title>
<path id="svg_3" d="m200,114l-114,95l26,97l99,20c0,0 19,-67 19,-68c0,-1 -1,-5 4,-8c5,-3 39,-10 40,-10c1,0 13,-2 14,-9c1,-7 -4,-36 -8,-40c-4,-4 -23,-15 -27,-17c-4,-2 -24,-16 -24,-23c0,-7 -1,-15 -1,-21c0,-6 -6,-19 -7,-19c-1,0 -21,3 -21,3z" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
<path id="svg_4" d="m244,101c0,0 14,55 16,56c2,1 22,11 24,13c2,2 23,17 24,18c1,1 1,28 -1,31c-2,3 -3,25 -9,30c-6,5 -32,14 -35,14c-3,0 -8,5 -10,8c-2,3 -10,37 -10,37c0,0 7,10 16,15c9,5 53,12 59,12c6,0 30,0 40,-8c10,-8 34,-7 35,-31c1,-24 1,-48 1,-65c0,-17 -13,-61 -15,-66c-2,-5 -21,-21 -21,-23c0,-2 34,-20 44,-15c10,5 29,24 33,28c4,4 10,20 16,5c6,-15 28,-31 -1,-46c-29,-15 -25,-24 -55,-25c-30,-1 -42,-5 -53,-5c-11,0 -46,-2 -52,1c-6,3 -46,16 -46,16z" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
<path id="svg_5" d="m428,180c0,0 -3,52 -4,53c-1,1 -2,27 -2,31c0,4 -8,29 -11,34c-3,5 -15,36 -21,38c-6,2 -77,18 -81,18c-4,0 -68,0 -68,7c0,7 -1,18 8,23c9,5 23,9 45,14c22,5 97,12 111,6c14,-6 44,-20 55,-30c11,-10 28,-28 37,-42c9,-14 14,-15 23,-40c9,-25 16,-109 12,-114c-4,-5 -32,-12 -45,-9c-13,3 -59,11 -59,11z" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

and css

```
path{
    fill:none;
    stroke:black;
}
path:hover{
    fill:red;
    stroke:blue;
}
```

Here is the fiddle, just hover them quickly.

http://jsfiddle.net/gWXbn/

Comment: tested it in firefox, chrome, last versions

Answer (score 81, accepted):

There's no fill so the interior does not catch mouse events by default and therefore hover doesn't react to that. Changing [pointer-events](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty) to all will fix it in this case:

```
path{
    fill:none;
    stroke:black;
    pointer-events:all;
}
```

Comment: If you want to trigger the event only on stroke/visible, use "pointer-events: stroke;" or "pointer-events: visible;".

Comment: Saved my life in 2018. Edit: "I'm a peer(reviewer) for the SVG subsystem". That's pretty neat!

Comment: Actually, pointer-events set to all does not fix the case, I tested it and succeed to reproduce the problem. Like you said, there is no fill, so the hover will not work even with pointer-event set to all. The solution is to set the fill with the background color (white) or transparent. And then, you will not have any problem, even if the cursor is moved quickly

Comment: doesn't work at all with multiple open (dashed) paths, as setting fill to transparent will always route the events then to the topmost path and its transparently filled interior.

Comment: Depends on your use case. Best ask a new question if you've a problem. Make sure you include a [mcve]

Comment: this fixed my problem where too fast mouseenter would not trigger mouseover

Answer (score 8):

The following fixed my problem with svg and jQuery hover and alike.

```
svg, svg * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This always works for me when using object tag

```
object {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```