# lagging mouse bahavior on SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'm working on a tooth selection menu for a web-app I'm building. I found an SVG and I'm modifying it.

I tried to simplify the mouse behavior, making only the large areas hoverable ('.parent') and the other stuff {pointer-events:none}. However, there's a major lag. When you move your mouse quickly into one of the teeth, it usually doesn't respond. Only when moving slowly into it.

Do you see that also? What can I do?

```
 $('.parent').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).css('fill', 'red');
});

$('.parent').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).css('fill', 'none');
});
```

[link to the codepen playground](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Vzyjra)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple change in the css fixed the issue:

```
svg *{
  pointer-events: none; // Disable pointer-events for all elements inside the SVG
}
svg .parent{
  pointer-events: all; // Enable pointer-events only on certain elements
}
```

Here's an updated version of your codepen: https://codepen.io/etiennemartin/pen/yovzZb

I also changed the way you trigger the `mouseover`, but that's just a personal preference. Looks cleaner to me.

Comment: was just about to add this as answer. Can we flag my Q as possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616233/css-hover-sometimes-doesnt-work-on-svg-paths ?

Comment: Thanks for the link, it helped me understand exactly what was going on. I flagged your Q as you asked.

Comment: For some reason the codepen went straight to the original version, not the one I had improved (the other teeth were included as well)... weird. But thanks!!