# Hover events for a dashed line in an SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg

An SVG with a line (or path) which uses `stroke-dasharray` only seems to trigger CSS and JS hover events when the user hovers over the solid parts of the dashed line: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YeXoZy

Is there a simple way to make both the JS and CSS events trigger when the solid or invisible parts of the line are hovered?

My current plan is to draw a second, invisible line following the same path and use it to detect mouse events. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BYNgRR This seems heavy handed and I'm hoping there's a cleaner way I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved somewhat by using a `rect` instead of `line` and using SVG `transforms` with `patterns`.

An example can be seen at [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MQwNaM?editors=1100).

[image]

It essentially bubbles down to:

```
<svg height="210" width="500">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="pattern1"
                width="10" height="10"
                patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                patternTransform="rotate(0 60 60)">
        <line stroke="green" stroke-width="12px" y2="10"/>
        </pattern>
        <pattern id="pattern2"
                width="10" height="10"
                patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                patternTransform="rotate(0 60 60)">
        <line stroke="red" stroke-width="12px" y2="10" stroke="transparent"/>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <g transform="rotate(45 60 60)">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="5"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

And the following CSS:

```
rect {
    fill: url(#pattern1)
}
    rect:hover {
    fill: url(#pattern2)
}
```

Comment: while this solves the OP's question for a line, this doesn't work for paths, circles, arcs, et cetera.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to do it without the second "detector" line, but a less heavy handed way is at least possible without the JS.

Switch the order of the lines, then you can use the hover selector as usual for the dashed line, then use `+` in a selector for the detector line to change the properties of the line immediately following it:

https://codepen.io/RyanGoree/pen/LQVKBV

Comment: Definitely solves the CSS event component but I need to trigger both a css hover event (for styling) and a JS event (for changing text elsewhere on the page), I don't think I made that clear enough in my question. Any thoughts on the js side?

Comment: Ah ok, I would just detect hover of the detector line since it is whole. Looks like your pen is already doing that. You've repeated the listener for the detector twice.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old topic I know. But found the answer on [Css hover sometimes doesn't work on svg paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616233/css-hover-sometimes-doesnt-work-on-svg-paths)

If you want to trigger the event only on stroke/visible, use `pointer-events: stroke;` or `pointer-events: visible;` (only the stroke) and `pointer-events: all;` (on both)

Here is a code example:

```html
<body>
    <div id="donut-score" class="svg-item" style="display: block;">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 40 40" class="donut">
            <circle class="donut-hole" cx="20" cy="20" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
            <circle class="donut-ring" cx="20" cy="20" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke-width="3.5"></circle>
            <circle id="donut-score-part-1" class="donut-segment donut-segment-1" onmousemove="this.style.stroke ='orange';" onmouseout="this.style.stroke = '#ff8197';" cx="20" cy="20" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke-width="3.5" stroke-dasharray="20 80" stroke-dashoffset="25"></circle>  
            <g class="donut-text-item donut-text-item">
                <text y="50%" transform="translate(0, 2)">
                    <tspan id="donut-score-text" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" class="donut-text">Score </tspan>
                    <tspan id="donut-score-aantal" x="50%" Y="65%" text-anchor="middle" class="donut-text">0 </tspan>
                </text>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
```

ccs:

```css
.donut-segment {
    stroke: #ff8197;
}

.svg-item {
    width:200px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.donut-text {
    font-size: 0.35em;
    line-height: 1;
    transform: translateY(0.5em);
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

If you add `pointer-events: stroke;` to the class `.donut-segment` then it only works on the stroke. If you use non or `pointer-events: all` it works on both. I tested it in codepen.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. None of the [pointer events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) options seem to enable pointer events on the unfilled part of the stroked line? Can you provide some code?

Comment: I had the problem that it triggered on both. With an inline onmouseover() then it looks like the default is pointer-events: all;  /svg only/

Comment: The code you've provided isn't an answer, it just seems to be another demo of the same problem?