# how to disable mouse hover when hovering specific jsplumb connection

Tags: jsplumb

I use JSPlumb Community Edition to dynamically build flowcharts from database.

In these flowcharts, some connectors should not be clickable.

I have been able to change the color of such connectors by registering two different connectors types, so users have a hint whether the connection is clickable or not.

```
            // define connection types
            const updatableHoverCSS = {
                strokeWidth: 3,
                stroke: '#876C4E',
                outlineWidth: 5,
                outlineStroke: 'white'
            };
            this.graphInstance.registerConnectionTypes({
                updatablePrerequisite: {
                    paintStyle: {
                        strokeWidth: 2,
                        stroke: '#FF9201',
                        outlineStroke: 'white'
                    },
                    hoverPaintStyle: updatableHoverCSS
                },
                notUpdatablePrerequisite: {
                    paintStyle: {
                        strokeWidth: 2,
                        stroke: '#8E1E07',
                        outlineStroke: 'white'
                    }
                }
            });
```

But I can't find out how to disable mouve hover effect, i.e. mouse changing from default to pointer, for connectors with type named 'notUpdatablePrerequisite".

About the issue on clickable dashed lines, here is my code on ngInit:

```
        this.graphInstance = newInstance({
            // default drag options
            dragOptions: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                zIndex: 2000,
                grid: [20, 20],
                containment: 'notNegative'
            },
            // overlays to decorate each connection with
            connectionOverlays: [
                {
                    type: 'Arrow',
                    options: {
                        location: 1,
                        visible: true,
                        width: 11,
                        length: 11,
                        id: 'ARROW'
                    }
                }
            ],
            container: document.getElementById('canvas')
        });
        // paint style for the connections hover style.
        const endpointHoverCSS = {
            fill: '#876C4E',
            stroke: '#876C4E'
        };
        // definition of source endpoints
        this.sourceEndpoint = {
            endpoint: DotEndpoint.type,
            paintStyle: {
                stroke: '#FF9201',
                fill: 'transparent',
                radius: 7,
                strokeWidth: 1
            },
            isSource: true,
            connector: { type: 'Flowchart', options: { stub: [40, 60], gap: 8, cornerRadius: 5, alwaysRespectStubs: false } },
            hoverPaintStyle: endpointHoverCSS,
            maxConnections: -1,
            dragOptions: {}
        };
        // definition of target endpoints (will appear when the user drags a connection)
        this.targetEndpoint = {
            endpoint: DotEndpoint.type,
            paintStyle: { fill: '#FF9201', radius: 7 },
            hoverPaintStyle: endpointHoverCSS,
            maxConnections: -1,
            dropOptions: { hoverClass: 'hover', activeClass: 'active' },
            isTarget: true
        };
```

And here is the code performed when the div containing the graph instance is updated:

```
                // define and style Connection Types
                const updatableOpenHoverCSS = {
                    stroke: '#FF9201'
                };
                const updatableLockedHoverCSS = {
                    stroke: '#FF9201',
                    dashstyle: '2 2'
                };
                const notUpdatableHoverCSS = {
                    stroke: '#FF9201',
                };
                this.graphInstance.registerConnectionTypes({
                    updatableOpenPrerequisite: {
                        paintStyle: {
                            strokeWidth: 2,
                            stroke: 'green'
                        },
                        hoverPaintStyle: updatableOpenHoverCSS
                    },
                    updatableLockedPrerequisite: {
                        paintStyle: {
                            strokeWidth: 2,
                            stroke: 'red',
                            dashstyle: '2 2'
                        },
                        hoverPaintStyle: updatableLockedHoverCSS
                    },
                    notUpdatableOpenPrerequisite: {
                        paintStyle: {
                            strokeWidth: 2,
                            stroke: '#8E1E07'
                        },
                        hoverPaintStyle: notUpdatableHoverCSS
                    },
                    notUpdatableLockedPrerequisite: {
                        paintStyle: {
                            strokeWidth: 2,
                            stroke: '#8E1E07',
                            dashstyle: '2 2'
                        },
                        hoverPaintStyle: notUpdatableHoverCSS
                    }
```

Also, I did not see dashed connectors on the demo you mention.

Here is a screen copy of the graph my code draws, where connection are dashed or not based on a boolean value retrieved from database.

[image]

On the first connector which is dashed, the mouve hover effect only appears on dashes, not between them.

Answer (score 0):

The mouse changing to `pointer` is a CSS issue, not something related to any of the paint styles you've got there. It looks like you have some `:hover` directive somewhere in your CSS. It would be something like:

```
.jtk-connector path:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. When I use dashed connections with hover effect, the hover effect is done only when the mouse is over a dash, not between two dashes. This is not a big issue, but is there a way to fix this?

Comment: That seems a little surprising. In the jsPlumb demonstrations, for instance

https://demo.jsplumbtoolkit.com/beta/flowchart-builder/

if you set a `stroke-dasharray`  on one of the connectors all the hover stuff still fires when hovering over the space between two dashes. How exactly are you implementing the hover?

Comment: I have completed my question with my code and a screen copy of my graph.

Comment: I also found this which seems to point the same issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555282/hover-events-for-a-dashed-line-in-an-svg