# Hover functionality not working on svg path

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I'm trying to get a :hover functionality on my svg path. In short, I want my path to fill with red when hovered over.

my CSS has:

```
.node_hover {
    /* fill-opacity: 1;
    fill: crimson;
    transition: 0.3s; */
    fill-opacity: 0;
}

.node_hover:hover {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    fill: black;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```

and my svg is

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 3269 4220" cursor = "pointer" pointerEvents = "all">
   <g className = "node_hover">
      <path id="Imported Path .... />
   </g>
</svg>
```

However nothing happens upon hover. I tried giving the className to my path itself but that doesn't work. either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Css hover sometimes doesn't work on svg paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616233/css-hover-sometimes-doesnt-work-on-svg-paths)

Comment: I tried the solutions suggested in that post, and nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is a typo. className should be class

```css
.node_hover {
    fill: black;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.node_hover:hover {
    fill: red;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 3269 4220" cursor = "pointer" pointerEvents = "all">
   <g class = "node_hover">
      <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
   </g>
</svg>
```